# Unique id for each element of a ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I have a `ListView` of `Items` and I need that each `element` has an unique `id`.

**But I have two conditions on my Items:**

- I can't use `index` because my `Items`**can be moved** (drag&drop), so their `index` will change.
- Each `Item` **can be displayed many times**, so there is no property of these elements that can help me to distinguish them.

My idea was to do something like that:

```
ListView {
    id: list
    property int uniqueId: 0

    width: 180; height: 200

    model: myModel

    delegate: Text {
        property int uniqueid: list.uniqueId
        text: uniqueid
    }
    Component.onCompleted: list.uniqueId++
}
```

But **it doesn't work** because when `list.uniqueId` is updated, it will update my Items id and **they will all have the same id** ( id = list.uniqueId)

How could I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you severe (or don't create) the binding, it will not auto update:

```
delegate: Text {
        Component.onCompleted: text = uniqueId++
}
```

However, I don't think avoiding this will really fix your design. What you should do is have the the unique id part implemented all the way back into the model data.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I thought it has the same behavior if you do it in a function.
I want to do that in the view because it is only a view problem and I don't want to change my data model. However, I need to think a little bit about it and you might be right.

Comment: Won't there be a problem, when you move the `ListView` and the delegates will be destroyed and created again?

Comment: That's what I hinted at. However, he might only want a unique id, but not a persistent one.